# What does the Jacobian matrix of this function look like

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

How do i find the Jacobian matrix of $f$:

$f: \boldsymbol{R^{n}} \rightarrow \boldsymbol{R^{n}} $

$f(x)=\frac{x}{\left \| x \right \|^{2}}$

Comment: Maybe it will help you if recognize the square of the norm of x as the dot product of x with itself?  You will also need to use the quotient rule.

Answer (score 0):

The $i$th component function of f is $$f_{i}(x_{1},...,x_{n})=\frac{x_{i}}{||x||^{2}}=\frac{x_{i}}{{x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}}}$$ You need to take all $n$ derivatives of this function, for each $i$.  At this point, it's just partial differentiation and quotient rule.  For example, $$\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}=\frac{(x_{1}^{2}+...x_{n}^{2})\delta_{ij}-2x_{i}x_{j}}{(x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2})^{2}}$$ where $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.